# Call event function in another event function As3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am calling function in another function like below:

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;


var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loadXML);

var xmlData:XML = new XML();

function loadXML(e:Event = null):void{

    xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
    //var production:String = xmlData.production.app_id.text();
    trace(xmlData);
    var states:String = xmlData.state.place.text();
    var desc:String = xmlData.state.description.text();
    var image:String = xmlData.state.image.text();
    trace('this is working');   
}
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest('test.xml'));
obj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,fl_MouseOverHandler);
function fl_MouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    loadXML();
}
```

In this case warning occured: `Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference` 
How do I resolve this? this above mentioned is the complete code.

Comment: You're not actually loading xml anywhere....  since you call `loadXML()` directly, e is null,  so since `e` is null,   you can't access a `target` property from it.

Comment: i have updated my code same warning on loading xml

Comment: First, it should show you the line with error. Second, since your `loadXML()` is an event listener that expects data, you should **never** call it manually with an empty event. Therefore, you should drop code that calls `loadXML()` and wait until completion, or add an event listener on [`ioError` and `securityError`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) to check if you are allowed to load that file and it actually loads.

Comment: and remove the default value `null` for the `Event` parameter because it doesn't make any sense to execute the function with that value as @Vesper explained. The opposite is true: you want to abort the function execution if `e == null`.

Comment: a null error is not a warning, it's an ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

when call your function without input then e.target is null and this is exception, you most use a "if".

your solution is:

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;


var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loadXML);

var xmlData:XML = new XML();

function loadXML(e:Event = null):void
{

    if (e!=null)
    {
        xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
    }
    //var production:String = xmlData.production.app_id.text();
    trace(xmlData);
    var states:String = xmlData.state.place.text();
    var desc:String = xmlData.state.description.text();
    var image:String = xmlData.state.image.text();
    trace('this is working');
}
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest('test.xml'));
obj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,fl_MouseOverHandler);
function fl_MouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    loadXML();
}
```

**Good Luck**